# Initializing NSMutableArray but the class of an initialized object displays as a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have initialized a mutable array like
 `NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`.
 I have printed the object class in NSLogs like
 `NSLog(@"object class is %@",[mutableArray class]);`. 
I have initialized a mutable array but the class of the object is displayed as `__NSArrayM`.
 
I try to add items to mutableArray then application is crashed. I don't know where is the problem. Please tell me why it is considered as a NSArray instead of NSMutableArray.

Thanks In Advace

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Please, add more code including the place where you are adding objects. Probably you are changing an iVar or property before adding objects.

Comment: `__NSArrayM` == `NSMutableArray`. Its correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is as expected, the `M` in `__NSArrayM` means mutable.

`NSArray` / `NSMutableArray` is a class cluster and you should never expect to see the class directly printed as `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: if that is a mutable array then why the application get crashed when try to add items to that array?

Comment: That's a different question and you need to show all of the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

For Immutable array it returns

```
__NSArrayI    // Here I is for Immutable
```

And for mutable it returns

```
__NSArrayM   // Here M is for Mutable
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are assigning a non mutable array to this mutable array or you are inserting nil objects. Could you post the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [mutableArray insertObject:object atIndex:0]; (for first)
    [mutableArray insertObject:object atIndex:[mutableArray count]]; (for last)
or  [mutableArray addObject:object];
```

How are you adding them?